# how to get the force being applied on an object in SpriteKit (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

So I am kinda new to SpriteKit and I am wondering how to get the amount of force on an object and put it into a variable. When you put force on an object, for example, this code,

```
line.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: -30))
```

it asks you how much in each direction. Well, I want to do the opposite. I want to get the amount of force that the object has and what direction.

Answer (score 0):

An impulse a force that lasts for a single instant. The object can only applies a force on another physics body when it collides relative to its velocity and mass.

If your looking to find your objects current avg speed, you use 
`sprite.physicsbody?.velocity`

or you can check if the object is moving with

```
physicsbody?.isResting
```

if you want to calculate the average force being applied on an object between frames you would have to calculate the magnitude of the change in position between the last update cycle and then multiply by the objects mass like so.

```
var lastPosition: CGPoint?
 var avgForce: CGPoint?

func updatedForce(for sprite: SKSprite, timeDelta: Double) {
guard let lastPosition = lastPosition, let currentVelocity = currentVelocity) else {
lastPosition = sprite.position
}

let position = sprite.position
let mass = sprite.physicsbody.mass
var changeInX = position.x - lastPosition.x
var changeInY = position.y - lastPosition.y
avgForce = CGPoint(x: changeInX * mass, y: changeInY * mass)
}`
```

I apologize for any formatting issues or incorrect spellings, made this from my iPhone and will correct later.

Comment: New question, is there a way to make an object completely stop all motion.

Comment: you can set its velocity to CGPoint.zero and/or set physicsbody.dynamic = false

Comment: Setting velocity to zero will stop movement but not stop other forces like gravity from accelerating it. Setting dynamic to be false will stop gravity and other physics objects/ forces from being applied or checked for by the physics simulation.

Comment: How do I set velocity to zero programattically

Comment: spriteObject.PhysicsBody.velocity = CGPoint.zero if I remember correctly off the top of my head

Comment: what do you mean by CGPoint.zero

Comment: its a static variable representing a cg point initialized too (0,0)

Comment: so give a code example for my situation with the line object that I set up

Comment: ok I already showed you 4 comments ago... heres the apple documentation on SKPhysicsBody: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody you may also want to research more on the swift programming language, types, classes, maybe pick up a good book. id recommend getting one from big nerd ranch.

Comment: id also check out raywenderlich.com, they are awesome

Comment: no but what I am asking is why there is a CGPoint, what is that supposed to mean.

Comment: CGPoint is a class provided in the CoreGraphics Framework By Apple and is used in coordinate systems for specifying location via x and y or for vectors, like velocity, to specify dy dx like in spritekit. So in this case setting the physics body to zero says there will be no movement in the x or y directions.

Comment: im sorry its a struct not a class.

Comment: I typed this : line.physicsBody.velocity = CGPoint.zero and I got an error, it said to add a question mark after physicsBody

Comment: so I did and then I got another error saying, " Cannot assign value of type ' CGPoint' to type 'CGVector' "

Comment: Ok... use a CGVector.zero instead. also the question mark means that PhysicsBody is a optional. All the answers to these questions are answered in the Apple doc links ive been giving you. if you plan on developing for Apple Devices you should learn to familiarize your self with them. Asking questions hat can be answered by the apple documentation may get some people annoyed as the answer is already in Xcode. Once again im currently on my phone but I believe documentation is under the help menu in the top menubar.